# Using a variable directory name in bash prevents me from seeing files in that directory

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

When I try to see the list of files in a variable name directory, the output is just my input.

```
read -e -p "Directory with images:" IMG_DIR
for file in $IMG_DIR/*; do echo "$file"; done
#if I input ~ at the terminal, ~/* and ~/.* is output
```

On the other hand, if the directory is static the output works fine:

```
for file in ~/{.,}*; do echo "$file"; done
#outputs all files in ~/ directory
```

Any idea why this is, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dmitri Churabov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38364710/45375) correctly diagnoses your problem (in short: only *literal*, unquoted `~` is ever expanded, never when stored in a *variable*), but **use of `eval` on user input is best avoided** for security reasons.

Instead, you can **roll your own tilde expansion using parameter expansion**:

```
read -e -p "Directory with images: " IMG_DIR
for file in "${IMG_DIR/#~/$HOME}"/*; do echo "$file"; done
```

This substitutes (`/`) the value of variable `$HOME` for literal `~` if it occurs at the beginning (`#`) of the `$IMG_DIR`'s value.

Comment: @mona_sax: I don't fully understand. Are you worried about a name collision between _variable_ `$file` and _external utility_ `file`?

Comment: Yeah that is what i meant.

Comment: @mona_sax: That's not really an issue, because you need `$` to reference _variable_ `file`, whereas there is no sigil when referring to _utility_ `file`.

Answer (score 3):

Expansion in the BASH command line occurs in a defined order where tilde expansion precedes parameter expansion. Therefore a `~` in a parameter value would not be expanded.

You can trigger tilde expansion using `eval`

```
 for file in "$( eval echo "$IMG_DIR" )"/* ; do echo "$file"; done
```

Here is an example:

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Directory with images:" IMG_DIR
file "$IMG_DIR"
file "$( eval echo "$IMG_DIR" )"
```

**Output:**

```
Directory with images:~
~: cannot open `~' (No such file or directory)
/home/username: directory
```

The first command `file "$IMG_DIR"` fails, while the second `file "$(eval echo "$IMG_DIR")"` succeeds.

Comment: Good explanation, but using `eval` on unchecked user input is ill-advised, and easily avoidable here. As an aside: your command substitutions should be double-quoted.